# Content types and modules

Tags: nodes, entities

I am new to Drupal and unsure how to add a module to a custom content type. I am currently trying to add the Field Quiz module to a custom content type on Drupal 8. Is it possible for someone to explain how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the question, Field Quiz simply provides a new field type/widget, so you have to edit the content type and add a new field using that type. It will be available after enabling the module.